# Determine the directory of a shared library

Tags: c, shared-libraries

Can anyone tell me if there is a way on both windows and linux platforms to determine the location of a shared library file from within a function call within the shared library. I have a shared library written in C which will be compiled and run both under linux and windows. I want to be able to determine from with a function the current location of the shared library so I can determine the location of some configuration and other files.

I've search for ways to do this but I can't find any answers now, although I'm sure I saw once an article that told how to do this in a platform specific way.

Comment: Update. It seems that on linux the addr function is the way to go. I'll try this but is there any windows equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain the full path for a DLL:

```
char path[MAX_PATH];
if (GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), path, MAX_PATH) &&
    ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER != GetLastError())
{
    char* last_slash = strrchr(path, '\\');
    if (last_slash) *last_slash = 0;
    printf("path=[%s]\n", path);
}
```

Output:

> path=[C:\WINDOWS\system32]